# Unable to link Global picklist value sets in Lightning Flow picklist Choice Set

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow, global-picklist

I have created 'Global Picklist Value Set' which one I have already linked in my custom sObject picklist field.

Now, I need to use same 'Global Picklist Value Set' in Screen Flow and link it with Flow's Picklist Choice Set.

Answer (score 0):

Global Value Sets can't be referenced directly in the Flow as a Choice Set. Instead you'll need to use a Picklist Choice Set that references a picklist field that uses the Global Value Set.